# How can I unpack a tuple struct like I would a classic tuple?

Tags: struct, rust, tuples, tuple-struct

I can unpack a classic tuple like this:

```
let pair = (1, true);
let (one, two) = pair;
```

If I have a tuple struct such as `struct Matrix(f32, f32, f32, f32)` and I try to unpack it, I get an error about "unexpected type":

```
struct Matrix(f32, f32, f32, f32);
let mat = Matrix(1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2);
let (one, two, three, four) = mat;
```

Results in this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:47:9
   |
47 |     let (one, two, three, four) = mat;
   |
   = note: expected type `Matrix`
              found type `(_, _, _, _)`
```

How can I unpack a tuple struct? Do I need to convert it explicitly to a tuple type? Or do I need to hardcode it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's simple: **just add the type name!**

```
struct Matrix(f32, f32, f32, f32);

let mat = Matrix(1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2);
let Matrix(one, two, three, four) = mat;
//  ^^^^^^
```

This works as expected.

---

It works exactly the same with normal structs. Here, you can bind either to the field name or a custom name (like `height`):

```
struct Point {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
}

let p = Point { x: 0.0, y: 5.0 };
let Point { x, y: height } = p;

println!("{x}, {height}");
```

Comment: Rust is hands down best language i've ever done.

Comment: So after the last "let Point" you can then println!("{height}"); and get output of 5 ?

Comment: @Pieter Yep. Edited my answer to include that.

Comment: and of course, after unpacking "p" is then invalid