# How do I extract a value from a tuple struct?

Tags: struct, rust

I have an object of a struct with one field from an external library, which is defined as: `pub struct SomeId(pub i64);`

Using `println!` to print the object shows this, for example: `SomeId(123)`

I created my own struct:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Something {
    pub id: i64,
}
```

And I'm trying to put value from external struct `SomeId` to field `id` in my struct `Something`:

```
let test = Something { id: ?? };
```

or extract value from struct `SomeId`:

```
let test: i64 = ??;
```

Comment: What is your question..? BTW, `SomeId` is a tuple struct, `Something` is a normal struct – not exactly apples and apples if you're asking about pattern matching.

Comment: [Related (unpacking tuple struct)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45624813/how-can-i-unpack-a-tuple-struct-like-i-would-a-classic-tuple/45624862)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should probably try

```
let test = Something { id: external_struct.0 };
```

or, to the second question,:

```
let test = external_struct.0;
```

These structs , of the form , `struct structname(variables...)` are called tuple structs and acts very similar to `tuples` in rust.

Comment: saying `let test = external_struct` creates a variable of type `SomeId` rather than `Something`.

Comment: Ah, I missed that `external_struct` was a `SomeId` since it was in the text rather than the code. :-P Apologies, my mistake.

Answer (score 9):

It's also possible to use struct destructuring to extract value from `SomeId`.

```
pub struct SomeId(pub i64);

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Something {
    pub id: i64,
}

fn main() {
    let some_id = SomeId(42);
    let SomeId(id) = some_id;
    let test = Something { id: id };
    let test: i64 = id;
}
```

[Link](https://rustbyexample.com/flow_control/match/destructuring/destructure_structures.html) to more examples.

Answer (score 2):

May be you are looking for something like the below?

```
pub struct SomeId(i32);

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Something {
    pub id: i32,
}


fn main() {
    let sid = SomeId(10);
    let sth = Something { id: sid.0 };
    println!("{:?}", sth);
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=11864886f47da124b15c0f33e1c9c3c2&version=stable)